# Swift how to change backIndicatorImage's position and size

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have got this code in my AppDelegate

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backarrow")
```

And this code shows something like this

[image]

How can i resize and change the position of the image?

Comment: this might help after getting the correct image size `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -80.0), forBarMetrics: .Default)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi you can implement it the following way: -

```
var backImage = UIImage(named: "backarrow")     
backImage = resizeImage(image: backImage!, newWidth: 40) //the width that you want for the back button image
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backImage
```

And here is the image resize function

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

    let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Comment: @sakoaskoaso sorry i named it incorrectly, i will update it and name it backImage

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the button by a custom one.
Define a `UIBarButtonItem` and replace the default one by your custom button.

```
var customButton =  UIBarButtonItem(image: closeButtonImage, style: .plain, target: self, action:  #selector(YourController.backPressed(_:)))
self.navigationItem. backBarButtonItem = customButton
```

Comment: How do i implement going back?

Comment: And do i implement it before pushing new viewcontroller or after?

Comment: You create a custom NavigationController that subclass the `UINavigationController` or define this in the prepareForSegue. I'm not sure it will works if you set this in the `viewDidLoad` of the `UIViewController`, but you can try.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a custom `UIBarButtonItem` and hide the default one.

```
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Your_Back_Button_Image", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popCurrentViewController)
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

To implement back functionality:

```
func popCurrentViewController(_ animated: Bool)
{
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You just have to implement it in the controller that is pushed and on which you want to show the custom back button.

Comment: custom bar buttons behave differently from the back button in several respects.